# Linkbutton's event in GridView not firing its event on 2nd Time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Seems to be a weird problem but my `Linkbutton` which is in `GridView` is not firing its event on `2nd Time.` 
**In Detail:**

 I have a `GridView` which has `linkButton` in it which is firing an event. This event is fired perfectly on **first time** but not working(not posting back) when i click it on **2nd time**.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dg1" runat="server" OnSorting="dg1_Sorting" OnRowCreated="GridViewSortImages"
   SkinID="grid" Width="100%" Font-Underline="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="false"
   OnRowCommand="dg1_RowCommand" AllowPaging="True" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
   OnRowDataBound="dg1_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtndel" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtndel_Click" ImageUrl="~/css/Images/delete.gif"
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to Delete')"></asp:ImageButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="15px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Type ID" SortExpression="ID" ItemStyle-Width="60px"
                    HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnno" runat="server" ForeColor="#123B61" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                            OnClick="lnkbtnno_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="False" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void lnkbtnno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    txtaccid.Text = lnkbtn.Text;

    Label lblDesc = lnkbtn.FindControl("lblDesc") as Label;
    txtdesc.Text = lblDesc.Text;

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is responsible for gridveiw data binding?

Answer (score 0):

your linkbutton not firing events for second time.Because some other events got fired in second time instead of your linkbutton. So in events stack linkbutton events got disabled. Checkit out whether you added dynamic control are firing or not. Make use developer tools like firebug(F12)